# How to set DataAnnotations for Date in Database First EF 6 on MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-database-first

There is a method to set format in Code First Migration

i.e:

```
..
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeliveredDate { get; set; }
..
```

However, I could achieve same logic in Database First Migration, since every change is the database is updating the models.

So, my question is: **How to set DataAnnotations like (DisplayFormat, DataFormatString so on.) in Database first migration? Is is possible? If possible, how to implement it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the fact that the generated entity classes are partial and associate metadata though another class and [MetadataTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

E.g., in some code file not affected by the code generation, you would write something like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(YourEntityMetadata))]
partial class YourEntity { }

class YourEntityMetadata
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeliveredDate { get; set; }
}
```

The "metadata" class does not need to include all properties of the entity - just the ones you want to associate data annotations with.

Reference: [**EF Database First with ASP.NET MVC: Enhancing Data Validation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation)

Answer (score 1):

You could change view model property with the [DisplayFormat] attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
               ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DeliveredDate { get; set; }
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DeliveredDate )
or, for displaying the value,

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DeliveredDate )
```

or you can do like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("MyDate", Model.DeliveredDate .ToLongDateString())
```

Comment: Ravikumar, I nowhere mentioned about EF migration. I want to set format for dataype. Like format for date, the format for currency. I can handle in Js. But I am looking for server side validation.